# Is it possible to conditionally loop through a table/set of values in a from one sheet in an excel workbook to another sheet?

Tags: excel

I have an excel workbook with various sheets of data and I am trying to write a formula that populates the information from one sheet `SheetA` into another one `SheetB`.

The issue is that the `SheetA` is regularly updated and when it is the order of the table changes. The table size is 12x16 (RXC) with headers and the first 2 on the columns on the far-most left contain the two Identifier tags/categorical variables that distinguish all numerical values in the cells to the right of them. There are only 2 different tags in the first column and 6 in the second with a (11 unique combinations total).

Given that the order of the table in `SheetA` is always changing, could anyone suggest an excel formula I could use to get value(s) from the table into a specific cell in `SheetB`

I tried my hand at doing this with VBA:

```
Sub formular()

Dim name As Range
Dim produce As Range
Dim TV As Worksheet
Dim TV_UPDATED Worksheet
Dim TV_UPDATED2 As Worksheet
Dim Wokbuk As Workbook


Set Wokbuk = Workbooks("BookofWok.xlsx")
Set TV = Workbooks("BookofWok.xlsx").Worksheets("TV Summary")
Set TV_UPDATED = Workbooks("BookofWok.xlsx").Worksheets("U1")
Set TV_UPDATED2 = Workbooks("BookofWok.xlsx").Worksheets("U2")

For Each name In U1.Range("a2:a12")
    If name.Value = "reezy plc" Then
        For Each produce In U1.Range("b2:b12")
            If produce.Value = "duce1" Then
                U1.Range("D4") = produce.Address().Offset(0, 1)
            Elseif produce.value = "duce2" Then
                U1.Range("D6") = produce.Address().Offset(0, 1)
            Elseif produce.value = "duce3" Then
                U1.Range("D7") = produce.Address().Offset(0, 1)
            Elseif produce.value = "duce4" Then
                U1.Range("D8") = produce.Address().Offset(0, 1)
            End If
    Next produce
    Elseif name.value = "yung plc" Then
        For Each produce In U2.Range("b2:b12")
            If produce.Value = "duce1" Then
                U2.Range("D4") = produce.Address().Offset(0, 1)
            Elseif produce.value = "duce2" Then
                U2.Range("D6") = produce.Address().Offset(0, 1)
            Elseif produce.value = "duce3" Then
                U2.Range("D7") = produce.Address().Offset(0, 1)
            Elseif produce.value = "duce4" Then
                U2.Range("D8") = produce.Address().Offset(0, 1)
            Elseif produce.value = "" Then
                U2.Range("D9") = produce.Address().Offset(0, 1)
            End If

        Next
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

But I got a 'compile error: invalid qualifier' at "produce.address". Could anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: SUMIFS perhaps.

Comment: I’m not wanting to sum the values though, just reference them in another sheet based on their unique combination.

Comment: If the combination is unique, then SUMIFS will work - it will only sum the value corresponding to the unique combination.

Comment: @BigBen I'm not sure I follow, could you give me an example?

Comment: Maybe [edit] your question with some sample data, and I'll throw together an example based on it.

Comment: @BigBen Just updated it.

Comment: Your question is becoming a moving target :) ... but don't use `Address` at all: `produce.Address().Offset(0, 1)` should just be `produce.Offset(0, 1).Value`.

Comment: Thanks for staying with it @BigBen :)... I've editted the code and I'm now getting a "compile error: syntax error" at the first elif condition.

Comment: There's no such thing as `elif` in VBA. `ElseIf`.

Comment: Hi @BigBen Thanks for that correction. The code is now running however, the macro?/code is meant to use the TV Summary Data sheet to populate both the u1 and u2 sheets with the appropriate column data based on the sonditions given.
Unfortunately, its populating both sheets with the values that come from the second For each block. Not sure where I've gone wrong so you're help would be greatly appreciated!!